# Order of colors if I do plt.savefit(). Red, Green, Blue?

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I do

```
plt.imshow(x)
plt.savefig('x.jpg')
```

where x is a numpy array with shape (height, width, number of channels), in what order matplotlib expects channels: 0) red, 1) green, 2) blue?
I ask this question, because the output image differs from cv2.imwrite()

Comment: https://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/

Comment: It looks like `imwrite` uses BGRA: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite